# GitLab: SSH access with key without granting access to whole webserver

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, shared-hosting, ssh-keys

The title sounds complicated, but my problem is dead simple, except I can't solve it.

I'm on shared hosting. An instance of gitlab is running besides some other stuff and is accessible from a subdomain (https://git.mydomain.com). When adding ssh-keys on my GitLab Profile page, I can also see them on my providers WebInterface for the webserver. Because I'm on shared hosting, I only have my default user. This means, if users add ssh keys to their profiles, they will also be able to access the webserver without any problems, because their keys have been added to my users authorized_keys file.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If GitLab users upload ssh keys in their profiles, the keys WILL show up in authorized_keys, BUT, they should include the following before the key:
`command="/path-to-shell/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell key-id",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty`

This limits users with that key to ONLY having access to that one command, and the other params are intended to ensure they cannot get to a terminal, or proxy through your server.

source: http://man.he.net/man5/authorized_keys (search for 'command=')

Comment: You might be right. Haven't checked that yet. But one problem still exists. Gitlab-shell seems to block normal shell access.

Comment: Aye, it blocks shell access for the gitlab-shell user (defaults to being called 'git') You should still be able to setup other system users to ssh in as. You just can't ssh into the machine as git.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Accepted answer. My problem: I'm on shared hosting and only have my default user.